# Prevent editting Enhanced Rich Text field directly inside the Details Pane

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, quick-edit

We have the following:-

1. Custom List inside sharepoint online modern site >> and we have disabled quick property editing:-

[image]

2. we have added a script editor web part to the edit form >> so when we edit an item it will be rendered inside the classic UI.
3. till now everything seems to be working well
4. but the issue is that if we select an item inside the list view >> the Details Pane will popup >> and we are able to directly edit an Enhanced Rich Text field named "Project Descritpion" inside the details pane >> although we have specified to disable quick property editing... this problem will only occur on the Enhanced Rich text editor fields.. so is there a way to fix this?

here are 2 screen shots of our issue:-

[image]

&

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.When you disable quick property editing, it means that you disable "Edit in the grid view".
[image]
2.The "Edit" button of enhanced rich text field is not controlled by disabling quick property editing. It cannot be removed by default. This is the default behavior for enhanced rich text filed in SharePoint Online modern experience.

Comment: so is this a bug in sharepoint then?

Comment: so is this a bug ? as i have some business logic inside the script editor web part inside the edit form and in other scenarios we have the business logic inside power app,,, where on some scenarios we disable the enhanced rich text editor if a status field = certain values.. but with the ability to edit the enhanced rich text directly inside the details pane will break this business logic as the field will always be enabled for editting....

Comment: one point to mention that recently the "Quick property editting" covers both the quick edit grid + details pane.. see the picture inside my question... so if we disable the Quick Property Editting (as i am doing) then it should also disable editing the field inside the details pane!!

Comment: If you feel this is a bug, you can log it via the Microsoft 365 admin center.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. When you disable quick property editing, it means that you disable editing items in the "Edit in the grid view" and details pane. It's not a bug. It's by design. There is currently no OOB solution or settings to remove the "Edit" button from details pane. You can either submit this request via SharePoint UserVoice forum.

Comment: @Emily Du - MSFT then it is a bug.. because we are disabling editing item inside the details pane but at the same time we are able to edit all the enhanced rich text editors fields inside the details pane !

Comment: You could open a ticket or service request for Microsoft.